# ¿Qué significa “patata agria”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones, vocabulario-técnico, comida

En [un vídeo de El Comidista](https://youtu.be/UJR1jzJFn1Y), alrededor de [1:25](https://youtu.be/UJR1jzJFn1Y?t=83) la cocinera dice:

> pues la patata es una **patata agria**.

Y se menciona una vez más en [3:30](https://youtu.be/UJR1jzJFn1Y?t=207).

Sé que es un tipo de patata, pero la traducción en inglés es “sour/bitter potato” y no entiendo. ¡Es tan extraño que una patata sepa agria o amarga!

¿Cuál es la etimología de la frase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser que "patata agria" no es una expresión, sino el nombre que recibe una variedad de patata. En [este blog de cocina](https://gastronomiaycia.republica.com/2010/03/19/patata-agria/) explican sus cualidades (tanto las que distinguen la variedad como la idoneidad de sus usos):

> La **patata agria** es una de las variedades de patata más demandadas por sus distintas cualidades, es de tamaño mediano-grande, tiene una forma ovalada y alargada, una piel fina, textura lisa y carne amarilla. La alaban como la patata ideal para fritura, lo que no implica que sea la mejor, pero es una patata compacta, tiene buen equilibrio de fécula y agua, pocos azúcares y buen peso, como resultado ofrece patatas fritas crujientes por fuera y tiernas por dentro.

El que se denomine "agria" no tiene necesariamente nada que ver con el sabor. Los nombres de otras variedades de patata no hacen necesariamente referencia ni al sabor ni al origen.

Mira [en este artículo](https://patatascatalan.es/patata-agria-caracteristicas/):

> Existen muchas variedades de patata: *Kennebec, Monalisa, Spunta*…pero quizás la más demandada por sus muchas y diversas cualidades sea la patata agria. Este tipo de tubérculo, de gran tamaño, forma ovalada, piel fina  y gran textura es, según muchos expertos, la patata ideal para freír debido a su buena combinación entre fécula y agua, sus pocos azúcares y su buen peso.

y [en este](https://www.jardineriaon.com/que-es-la-patata-agria.html)

> [..] pero, ¿sabías que hay muchas variedades [de patata]? Entre ellas están la *Monalisa* o la *Spunta*, aunque sin duda la más demandada es la patata agria.

[Este otro](https://plantasyflores.online/patata/agria/) hace referencia a nombres de patata por su origen (gallega, francesa), pero además clarifica (que los artículos anteriores no lo hacen) que el nombre de "agria" para la variedad no tiene nada que ver con el sabor.

> No os dejéis engañar por su nombre, la patata agria es una patata excelente, con buen sabor y que es de las mejores variedades para freír.
> [...]
>
> Mi teoría es que el nombre ha influido a que no se vendan en las tiendas. Las pocas tiendas que ponen algo más que patata nueva o sucia ponen otro tipo de patatas como *gallega*, *potato*, etc. porque tienen nombres bonitos. Por el contrario, el concepto agrio nos hace pensar que es una patata mala, podrida o de mal sabor.
>
> Un error de marketing muy grande.

Aunque no he encontrado la etimología del nombre para esta variedad, sí que he visto que se traduce como "Agria potato" en inglés (y no "sour potato"), por ejemplo en [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/patata+agria.html). Esto puede darnos a entender que el nombre de "agria" puede ser sencillamente casualidad (referencia a una región u otra cosa) y no al sabor (como se explica en los blogs, esta patata no tiene nada de agria en el sabor).